# The API Vimeo Config doesn't return progressive URL anymore?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I use the API `https://player.vimeo.com/video/{vimeo_id}/config` to get the streaming URL from the JSON response.

But Now the API doesn't return the Streaming URL anymore if it's a new video upload. The old one still has it.

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not ask Vimeos support about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Correct method to get the video files and progressive URL's are

GET [https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}](https://api.vimeo.com/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D)

This method returns a single video.

video_id *  Number  The ID of the video.

You can refer for it here : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video

Get video file and download links from the API
This feature requires a Vimeo Standard and higher or Vimeo Pro and higher membership.

The method you are using isn't valid anymore, you can contact Vimeo Support for further questions